# Nativescript doInBackground Thrown and Cause OutOfMemory Error

Tags: android, performance, error-handling, out-of-memory, nativescript

I am new at nativescript and developing programs about a few months. I got same error and I am using radList view and Web image cache plugins. We got an api for sending products and their images and images about 500kb. And I am making tab from their categories and in category i am making a list view for each category and listing products inside it. My code like that;

```
var tabView = page.getViewById("tabViewContainer");
    var meal_list = config.meal_list;
    meal_list.forEach(function (item) {
        var items = new observable_array_1.ObservableArray();
        item.meal_list.forEach(function (item2) {
            items.push(new DataItemWithImage(item2.meal_id, item2.meal_name, item2.meal_cost,"http://sezginserpen.com.tr/test_image/" + item2.meal_id + ".jpg"));
          //  items.push(new DataItemWithImage(item2.meal_id, item2.meal_name, item2.meal_cost,"http://pngimg.com/upload/pizza_PNG7132.png"));
        });
        var wrapLayout = new wrapLayoutModule.WrapLayout();
        var radListView = new listViewModule.RadListView();
        var layoutBase = new listViewModule.ListViewGridLayout();
        layoutBase.scrollDirection = "Vertical";
        layoutBase.spanCount = 2;
        wrapLayout.className = "item";
        wrapLayout.orientation = "horizontal";
        radListView.listViewLayout = layoutBase;
        radListView.items = items;//<IC:WebImage stretch="fill" height="250" class="my-image-1" src="{{ image }}></IC:WebImage>
        radListView.itemTemplate = '<Border xmlns:IC="nativescript-web-image-cache"  borderWidth="0.5" borderColor="lightgray"><stack-layout orientation="vertical" height="250" ><IC:WebImage horizontalAlignment="center"  src="{{ image }}"></IC:WebImage><stack-layout  width="100%" height="50%"> <label id="product_id_label" text="{{ id }}" style="visibility: collapsed" /><label class="align_center product_label" textWrap="true"  text="{{ itemName }}" /> <label class="align_center product_label" textWrap="true" style="color:lightgray" text="{{ itemDescription }}" /> <Border  borderWidth="1" borderColor="green" borderRadius="2" style="height:22%;width:95%"> <label tap="add_to_basket" class="align_center" style="background-color:white;color:green;" text="Sepete Ekle" /> </Border> </stack-layout> </stack-layout> </Border>';
        wrapLayout.addChild(radListView);
        var tabViewItem = new tabViewModule.TabViewItem();
        tabViewItem.title = item.category.category_name,
            tabViewItem.view = wrapLayout;
        var tabView = page.getViewById("tabViewContainer");
        tabView.items.push(tabViewItem);
    });
```

AND XML like;

```
<drawer:rad-side-drawer id="drawer">
      <drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>
        <!-- Home page contents -->
        <stack-layout loaded="contentLoaded">
            <TabView id="tabViewContainer" selectedIndex="{{ index }}" selectedColor="#d43b2b" selectedIndexChanged="change"   tabsBackgroundColor="#ffffff"  >
                <TabView.items>
                </TabView.items>
            </TabView>
        </stack-layout>
      </drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>
      <drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
        <widgets:drawer-content />
      </drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
    </drawer:rad-side-drawer>
```

Any idea for what causing this ? And I am using ımagecache but every time got this. And one of my Stack Trace1:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 12939040 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:763)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$RequestResult.readResponseStream(Async.java:225)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:303)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:253)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 3 more
```

Trace2:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1508364 byte allocation with 301952 free bytes and 294KB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:975)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:946)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:913)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:55)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:30)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BasePool.get(BasePool.java:259)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeStaticImageFromStream(ArtDecoder.java:137)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeFromEncodedImage(ArtDecoder.java:81)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.ImageDecoder.decodeStaticImage(ImageDecoder.java:128)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.ImageDecoder.decodeImage(ImageDecoder.java:94)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.doDecode(DecodeProducer.java:194)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.access$200(DecodeProducer.java:97)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder$1.run(DecodeProducer.java:129)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.doJob(JobScheduler.java:207)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.access$000(JobScheduler.java:27)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler$1.run(JobScheduler.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This one is another and does not about this eror types but i got this too  :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.bringToFront()' on a null object reference
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.transitions.DrawerTransitionBase.setProgress(DrawerTransitionBase.java:77)
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.transitions.DrawerTransitionBase.onEnded(DrawerTransitionBase.java:226)
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.transitions.DrawerTransitionBase.run(DrawerTransitionBase.java:221)
    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1119)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1239)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:766)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler$1.run(ValueAnimator.java:801)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:628)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

And any idea About how can I catch this types of Error??

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Perhaps this issue has been caused be loading the images inside the listview. As a solution for Android you could use nativescript-fresco -https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco plugin to display the images in the listview. you could find example here -  https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/release/sdk/app/listview/item-layouts/item-layouts-grid.android.xml

Comment: Thank you for your helping and I am already using IC WebCache image including Fresco and another plugin for İOS. And I realize this errors come from a plugin called https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-slides and When I dont use this plugin There no error even big images. Only got errors cause of big images example 4mb or even more :) And do you know any other plugin for slider ?

Comment: I was unable to find another plugin similar to `nativescript-slides`.  I am not sure whether this is applicable for your project, however you could use `TabView`, which also supports swipe between the pages.

Comment: I found that one of the NativeScript community members made plugin similar to `nativescript-slides`. You could find working example here - https://github.com/NordlingArt/nativescript-na-slideshow , however the example is available only for ios at the moment.

Comment: Oh tank you for interests ı Will be try it net time and is there any method for hiding tabi view tabi titles??

Comment: you could review my answer below, where has been shown how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below-attached example shows, how you could remove tabs from TabView in NativeScirpt for both iOS and Android.

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <TabView id="tabViewContainer" loaded="tabviewLoaded">
      <TabView.items>
          <TabViewItem title="">
              <TabViewItem.view>
                  <Label text="This is Label in Tab 1" />
              </TabViewItem.view>
          </TabViewItem>
          <TabViewItem title="">
              <TabViewItem.view>
                  <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2" />
              </TabViewItem.view>
          </TabViewItem>
      </TabView.items>
  </TabView>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
  import { EventData } from "data/observable";
    import { Page } from "ui/page";
    import {TabView} from "ui/tab-view";
    import {isAndroid, isIOS} from "platform"



    export function tabviewLoaded(args:EventData){

        var tabview =<any> args.object;

         if(isAndroid){
            var tabViewgrid = tabview._grid;
            console.dump(tabViewgrid.removeViewAt(0));
         }

         if(isIOS){
            tabview._ios.tabBar.hidden = true;
         }
    }
```

main-page.js

```
var platform_1 = require("platform");
function tabviewLoaded(args) {
    var tabview = args.object;
    if (platform_1.isAndroid) {
        var tabViewgrid = tabview._grid;
        console.dump(tabViewgrid.removeViewAt(0));
    }
    if (platform_1.isIOS) {
        tabview._ios.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }
}
exports.tabviewLoaded = tabviewLoaded;
```

Comment: I tried this and its working good but sometimes i will get errors again doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309) like this and İ couldnt resolve it :(